# No border on first page when using \fcolorbox and \fancypage

Tags: color, fancybox

I'm using `\fcolorbox` (from `xcolor`) within `\fancypage` (from `fancybox`) to get a coloured page border. Unfortunately the first page does not show a border, even though the box itself is drawn. How can I get this MWE to work (that is to show the red border on the first page)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox, xcolor, lipsum}

\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Note that using `\fancypage{}{\fbox}` shows the border on the first page as expected.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples.

Comment: It is a problem with `xcolor` or `xcolor`'s interaction with `fancypage`, it seems.

Comment: `fancybox` replaces the output routine of LaTeX2e with a modified version of the old one in LaTeX 2.09. Avoid it.

Comment: @egreg what is a good alternative to fancybox in this case (i.e. to draw a frame around the text in each page)?

Comment: @ctef Nowadays I'd say TikZ.

Comment: @egreg I thought you would say Ti*k*Z is overkill ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative using Ti*k*Z and the `everypage` package. The idea is based on code in the `background` package. `tikzpagenodes` is used to get easy access to coordinates corresponding to the various parts of the page.

One advantage is that you may, if you wish, create much fancier frames and backdrops.

This example draws one background which includes the text block, header and footer (but not the marginal notes) and another overlaying it which includes just the text block. I've used shadings just to give an idea of the simpler possibilities.

[image: fancy backgrounds in blue]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{% based on background.sty
    \node [top color=blue!50!cyan, bottom color=blue!50!cyan, middle color=blue!25!cyan, draw=blue!75!cyan, line width=3.5pt, inner ysep=15pt, inner xsep=25pt, fit=(current page footer area.south west) (current page header area.north east)] {};
    \node [top color=blue!25!cyan, bottom color=blue!25!cyan, middle color=white, draw=blue!50!cyan, line width=2.5pt, inner sep=5pt, fit=(current page text area.south west) (current page text area.north east)] {};
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `tcolorbox` package with the `breakable` library allow you to make  colored boxes and frames that allow page breaks, among many other well-documented options.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,paperheight=9cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
colback=blue!20!, colframe=red!75!black,
boxsep=3mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=2pt]
\lipsum[1-50] % long bla bla bla
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Edit: I you want headers/footers inside the box, one solution could be one unbreakable `tcolobox` using the `background` package:

> [image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!10!, 
colframe=red!75!black, boxsep=3mm,
arc=0mm,boxrule=2pt]% 
\vspace{\textheight} 
\end{tcolorbox}
},angle=0,scale=1.2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\LaTeX\ examples}
\lhead{Background boxes}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My first answer was an emulation of `\fancypage{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}{}`. See this solution below.
However, the question was about `\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}`. So first here comes my solution for that.

**1. Solution for `\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}`**

Here is a lightweight solution (no additional packages needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}
\newcommand{\xcoord}{1in+\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}
\newcommand{\ycoord}{-1in-\voffset-\textheight-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-\fboxsep}
\newlength\boxheight
\setlength\boxheight{\dimexpr\textheight+\footskip+\headheight+\headsep+\fboxsep}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put(\xcoord,\ycoord){%
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\vbox to \boxheight{\hspace{\textwidth}}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

If you have an older LaTeX that doesn't support the `shipout/background` hook, this can be emulated with the `everypage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage}

%\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}
\newcommand{\xcoord}{\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}
\newcommand{\ycoord}{-\voffset-\textheight-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\footskip-\fboxsep}
\newlength\boxheight
\setlength\boxheight{\dimexpr\textheight+\footskip+\headheight+\headsep+\fboxsep}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \put(\xcoord,\ycoord){%
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\vbox to \boxheight{\hspace{\textwidth}}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

**2. Solution for `\fancypage{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}{}`**

Here is a lightweight solution (no additional packages needed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\fancypage{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}{}
\newcommand{\xcoord}{1in+\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}
\newcommand{\ycoord}{-1in-\voffset-\textheight-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\fboxsep}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put(\xcoord,\ycoord){%
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\vbox to \textheight{\hspace{\textwidth}}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

If you have an older LaTeX that doesn't support the `shipout/background` hook, this can be emulated with the `everypage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage}

%\fancypage{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}}{}
\newcommand{\xcoord}{\ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}
\newcommand{\ycoord}{-\voffset-\textheight-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\fboxsep}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \put(\xcoord,\ycoord){%
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\vbox to \textheight{\hspace{\textwidth}}}
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```